# Get UIButton's title set with UIControlStateHighlighted

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

If a button's title is set with `UIControlStateHighlighted`, how can that title later be accessed?  The `currentTitle` method doesn't work, as it only returns what is currently being displayed by the button.

For example, say a button's title is set like this:

```
[myButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

How can this title then be retrieved from `myButton`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
NSString *highlightedTitle = [myButton titleForState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
myButton.highlighted=YES;
NSString *title=[myButton currentTitle];
myButton.highlighted=NO;
```